# How to have multiple views in a recyclerview

Tags: java, android, view, android-recyclerview

I would like to have multiple views in my RecyclerView. I would like to use the "card_view_row_pauze" when the word "pauze" is passed, and I want to use the "card_view_row" when there isn't the word "pauze" passed. I tried some things (see the comments I added in the code) but it just didn't work. I found some answers on stackoverflow, but I cannot seem to implement it, unfortunately. How can I do so?

MyRecyclerViewAdapter.java

```
package com.company.app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView .Adapter<MyRecyclerViewAdapter .DataObjectHolder> {
    private ArrayList<DataObject> mDataset;
    private static MyClickListener myClickListener;
    private Activity mActivity;

    public static class DataObjectHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View .OnClickListener {
        TextView label;
        TextView dateTime;
        TextView tijd;
        CardView cardView;

        public DataObjectHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            label = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            dateTime = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            tijd = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
            cardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override public void onClick(View v) {
            myClickListener.onItemClick(getAdapterPosition(), v);
        }
    }

    ViewGroup myParent; // THIS I ADDED TO SUPPORT MULTIPLE VIEWS

    public void setOnItemClickListener(MyClickListener myClickListener) {
        this.myClickListener = myClickListener;
    }

    public MyRecyclerViewAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<DataObject> myDataset) {
        mDataset = myDataset;
        mActivity = activity;
    }

    @Override public DataObjectHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,int viewType) {
        myParent = parent; // THIS I ADDED TO SUPPORT MULTIPLE VIEWS
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_view_row, parent, false);
        DataObjectHolder dataObjectHolder = new DataObjectHolder(view);
        return dataObjectHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(DataObjectHolder holder, final int position) {
        if (mDataset.get(position).getmText1().equals("Pauze")) { //HERE I WANT TO USE THE "card_view_row_pauze" VIEW WHEN THE PASSED TEXT CONTAINS "PAUZE"
            View viewd = LayoutInflater.from(myParent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_view_row_pauze, myParent, false);
            DataObjectHolder dataObjectHolderd = new DataObjectHolder(viewd);
            dataObjectHolderd.label.setText(mDataset.get(position).getmText1());
            dataObjectHolderd.tijd.setText(mDataset.get(position).getmText3());
        }
        else {
            holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String myDescription = mDataset.get(position).getDescription();
                    if (myDescription.length() >= 2) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.getMain().getApplicationContext(), myDescription, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
            holder.label.setText(mDataset.get(position).getmText1());
            holder.dateTime.setText(mDataset.get(position).getmText2());
            holder.tijd.setText(mDataset.get(position).getmText3());
        }
    }

    public void addItem(final DataObject dataObj, final int index) {if (mActivity == null){return;}

        mActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() {
                mDataset.add(index, dataObj);
                notifyItemInserted(index);
            }
        });
    }

    public void deleteItem(int index) {
        mDataset.remove(index);
        notifyItemRemoved(index);
    }

    @Override public int getItemCount() {return mDataset.size();}
    public interface MyClickListener {public void onItemClick(int position, View v);}
}
```

DataObject.java

```
package com.company.app;

public class DataObject {
    private String mText1;
    private String mText2;
    private String mText3;
    private String mState;
    private String mDescription;

    DataObject (String text1, String text2, String text3, String state, String description){
        mText1 = text1;
        mText2 = text2;
        mText3 = text3;
        mState = state;
        mDescription = description;
    }

    public String getmText1() {return mText1;}
    public void setmText1(String mText1) {
        this.mText1 = mText1;
    }
    public String getmText2() {
        return mText2;
    }
    public void setmText2(String mText2) {
        this.mText2 = mText2;
    }
    public String getmText3() {
        return mText3;
    }
    public void setmText3(String mText3) {
        this.mText3 = mText3;
    }
    public String getmState() {
        return mState;
    }
    public void setmState(String mState) {
        this.mState = mState;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return mDescription;
    }
    public void setDescription(String mDescription) {
        this.mDescription = mDescription;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create Two ViewHolder with Pauze and row xmls. And In ItemViewType check for text Value from your data source and according to that Inflate specific ViewHolder.

Here is Some code for this.

```
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (products.size()==0){
            return 0;
        }else if (viewFormat== Constants.listV){
            return Constants.listV;
        }else if (viewFormat==Constants.gridV){
            return Constants.gridV;
        }
        return super.getItemViewType(position);
    }
```

And ViewHolder:

```
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        if (viewType== Constants.gridV){
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.product_items,parent,false);
            return new MovieViewHolder(view);
        }else if (viewType==Constants.listV)
        {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.linear_item_view,parent,false);
            return new OtherViewHolder(view);
        }else{
            return null;
        }
    }
```